# Printing a form

Tags: c#, .net, printing

Can I have a button in my form which shows the print dialog box so that the user can print that form?

Comment: You need to rephrase your question.

Comment: Charlie, why? I think I understand the question just fine.

Answer (score 2):

I think [this example from Microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa287529%28VS.71%29.aspx) might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Attach this to your button:

```
onclick="javascript:window.print()"
```

Not ideally semantic, but it works.